# CameraX - No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : null. May be attempting to bind too many use cases

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm using CameraX in my project and now and then I can see this weird error poping up and crashing my application. This happens to some devices - not all.

I start my camera like this:

```
private fun startCamera() {
    if (!isAdded) {
        return
    }

    val textureView = rootView?.findViewById<TextureView>(R.id.textureView)

    if (textureView != null) {
        val display = (requireActivity().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay

        if (metrics == null) {
            metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { display.getRealMetrics(it) }
        }

        config = CameraConfiguration(
            aspectRatio = Rational(metrics!!.widthPixels, metrics!!.heightPixels),
            resolution = Size(metrics!!.widthPixels, metrics!!.heightPixels)
        )

        CameraX.unbindAll()
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(
            this,
            buildPreviewUseCase(),
            buildImageAnalysisUseCase(),
            buildImageCaptureUseCase()
        )
    }
}
```

Use cases are build like this:

```
private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(config.aspectRatio)
        .setTargetResolution(config.resolution)
        .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
        .setLensFacing(config.lensFacing)
        .build()

    return AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(previewConfig, cameraTextureView)
}

private fun buildImageCaptureUseCase(): ImageCapture {
    val captureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(config.aspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
        .setTargetResolution(config.resolution)
        .setCaptureMode(config.captureMode)
        .setLensFacing(config.lensFacing)
        .build()

    val capture = ImageCapture(captureConfig)

    takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener {

        capture.takePicture(object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onError(useCaseError: ImageCapture.UseCaseError?, message: String?, cause: Throwable?) {
                ...
            }
        })
    }

    return capture
}

private fun buildImageAnalysisUseCase(): ImageAnalysis {
    val analysisConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
        val analyzerThread = HandlerThread("Analyzer").apply { start() }
        analyzerHandler = Handler(analyzerThread.looper)

        setCallbackHandler(analyzerHandler!!)
        setTargetAspectRatio(config.aspectRatio)
        setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
        setLensFacing(config.lensFacing)
        setTargetResolution(config.resolution)
        setImageReaderMode(config.readerMode)
        setImageQueueDepth(config.queueDepth)
    }.build()

    val analysis = ImageAnalysis(analysisConfig)
    analysis.analyzer = ImageRecognitionAnalyzer(viewModel)

    return analysis
}
```

Is there a way to fix this and can someone explain what exactly is happening? Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : null.  May be attempting to bind too many use cases.
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getSuggestedResolutions(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:180)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.calculateSuggestedResolutions(CameraX.java:449)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.bindToLifecycle(CameraX.java:144)
    at com.s.v.f.i.views.CameraFragment.startCamera(CameraFragment.kt:554)
```

Comment: I am also looking for some exceptionhandling mechanism in camerax
I have an old phone where the camera does not open sometimes I had unspecified errors until I reboot my phone.
Are you able to implement the state callbacks of the api???

Comment: @PembaTamang What are u referencing to state callbacks? App works perfect on samsung, for instance. I dont think those things affect each other

Comment: I tried camerax for the first time yesterday when I ran my code I saw an error and it was caught by the code in the readonly classes, internal classes I mean, a `onError` inside the `CameraDevice.StateCallback`. So is there a way that I can handle the error and show the user some info rather than have the app crash.

Comment: I'm more interested in what is causing this and how can I avoid it programatically. I do not want user to show error as that would cause bad experience for him. But thanks for input. It's good to know that I'm not the only one experiencing this.

Comment: I followed the codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#4
its good but it does not say anything about the state callbacks or handling errors

Comment: sometimes you need to tell the user to reboot the phone, so you need to handle the error, do you have an idea how??

Comment: like whatsapp  and othe apps do https://u01.appmifile.com/images/2018/02/27/52fd832f-fc7d-4301-ba94-ed4177f78ac7.png

Comment: @MaartinAndroid - Did you resolve this issue